# Difference in meaning: happen to know vs. know

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Is there a pretty big difference in meaning between two sentences?

I just want to know the meaning 'happen to.'

1. Do you know that she got married?
2. Do you happen to know if she got married?

Comment: 1) is fine. 2) 'happen to' is superfluous, but okay. "Do you happen to know **if**  she got married?" is a question.

Answer (score 0):

### **"Happen to"**

1. *"do something or be somewhere by chance" (accidentally)*:

   - If you *happen to find* it make sure to take it with you.
   - If, by any chance, you *happen to be* in that shop today then would you be so kind as to buy me that dress I showed you, please. (A very superfluous sentence)
2. "ask something politely":

   - Do you *happen to have* a pen I can borrow?
3. Used for expressing an opinion firmly, because you are angry:

   - I *happen to live* here too so don’t leave your rubbish everywhere!
4. An event or action takes place which affects you and used for talking about the way that something changes or develops something.

   - This is the best thing that’s ever *happened to* me.
   - We don’t understand what is *happening to* the economy.

In your examples:

- Do you know that she got married? (did somebody tell you?, did you read it out somewhere?)
- Do you happen to know that she got married? (is rather odd, the better way of saying it is: Do you happen to know if she got married) - This means: By any chance did you know it? Is there any chance of you finding out about it?

Another possible solution is to put in the past:

- Did you happen to know if she got married? (Did you, by any chance, find out this information? Overheard it somewhere?)